# Discord Giveaway Command

Tags: python, discord, bots

I do a Discord Bot with a couple of commands but the giveaway command (Verlosung) doesn't sent the winner Message after the time in the command is over. If nobody participates, the message comes that not enough have participated, but as soon as someone participates, there is no message at all.

All other functions work, only this giveaway command caused stress from the start. Maybe you know where the error is and can tell me?

```
import discord
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True


class ValeCraftBot(commands.Bot):
  winners = 1  # Anzahl der Gewinner festlegen

  def __init__(self, command_prefix, intents, token):
    super().__init__(command_prefix=command_prefix, intents=intents)
    self.token = token


bot = ValeCraftBot(
  command_prefix='!',
  intents=intents,
  token=
  'BOT_TOKEN')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user.name} : Ich bin bereit mein großer Herscher und Meister!')


@bot.command(name='umfrage')
async def poll(ctx, *, question):
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title="---------------",
    description=f"{question}\n\n:white_check_mark: oder :x:",
    color=2105893)
  embed.set_author(
    name="Wir brauchen deine Meinung!",
    icon_url=
    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1089918290459115610/1091869819298660472/vprofilbild_-_Kopie.png"
  )
  embed.set_footer(
    icon_url=
    "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1089918290459115610/1091869819298660472/vprofilbild_-_Kopie.png",
    text="Viel Spaß auf Vale-Craft!")

  message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await message.add_reaction("\U00002705")  # Emoji-ID für das Häkchen (✅)
  await message.add_reaction("\U0000274C")  # Emoji-ID für das Kreuz (❌)


@bot.command(name='verlosung')
async def giveaway(ctx, name, duration, winners):
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title=name,
    description=f"Gewinner werden in {duration} Sekunden ausgewählt",
    color=0xffd700)
  embed.set_author(name="Verlosung", icon_url=bot.user.avatar.url)
  message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await message.add_reaction("")  # Reaktion zur Teilnahme hinzufügen

  def check(reaction, user):
    return user != bot.user and str(
      reaction.emoji) == "" and reaction.message.id == message.id

  try:
    await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=int(duration), check=check)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    if len(message.reactions) < 1 or message.reactions[0].count < 2:
      winners_text = "Es gab keine Teilnehmer für die Verlosung."
    else:
      participants = await message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
      bot_user = message.guild.get_member(bot.user.id)
      if bot_user in participants:
        participants.remove(bot_user)
      if len(participants) < 1:
        winners_text = "Es gab keine Teilnehmer für die Verlosung."
      else:
        if len(participants) < int(winners):
          winners_text = "Es gab nicht genügend Teilnehmer für die Verlosung."
        else:
          winner = random.choice(participants)
          winners_text = f"{winner.mention} hat die Verlosung Gewonnen. Herzlichen Glückwunsch!"

    winners_embed = discord.Embed(title="Gewinner",
                                  description=winners_text,
                                  color=0xffd700)
    winners_embed.set_author(name="Verlosung", icon_url=bot.user.avatar.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=winners_embed
                   )  # Gewinnerbenachrichtigung im Chat senden


@bot.command(name='hilfe')
async def help_command(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Vale-Craft Bot Hilfe",
    description="Hier ist eine Liste der verfügbaren Befehle:",
    color=0x7289DA)
  embed.add_field(name="!umfrage <Frage>",
                  value="Erstellt eine Umfrage mit der angegebenen Frage.",
                  inline=False)
  embed.add_field(
    name="!verlosung <Name> <Dauer in Sekunden> <Gewinneranzahl>",
    value=
    "Startet eine Verlosung mit dem angegebenen Namen, Dauer und der Anzahl der Gewinner.",
    inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text="Viel Spaß mit dem Bot!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)


bot.run(
  'BOT_TOKEN')
```

Maybe you know why there is no winner message?

Answer (score 0):

In the giveaway command, you have defined the ***winners*** parameter, but you're not using it. Instead, you're referring to the ***winners class variable*** defined in the ***ValeCraftBot*** class. To fix this, remove the ***winners*** parameter from the giveaway command and use the ***self.winners*** variable instead. Make sure to update the rest of your code accordingly, removing the winners parameter from the giveaway command in other parts of your code.